# Run from command line SSIS package generated with Import wizard

Tags: ssis, oracle10g, sql-server-2008-r2, data-migration

With the Import wizard from SQL Server 2008 R2 I created a dtsx package to extract data from an Oracle database to SQL server. In the wizard steps, I edited the SQL Script command in order to create new tables during the migration.

In the wizard steps I chosed "Don't save sensitive data" in the package protection level area.

The generated command line is:

```
dtexec.exe /FILE import_data.dtsx 
CONNECTION DestinationConnectionOLEDB; Data Source=source;Initial Catalog=TEST;
           Provider=SQLNCLI10; Integrated Security=SSPI;Auto Translate=false; 
CONNECTION SourceConnectionAdoNET;Data Source=Oracle;PASSWORD=XYZ;User ID=Ned;  
CHECKPOINTING OFF  
REPORTING EWCDI
```

However I am always getting the following exception:

```
Error: 2013-03-08 09:54:55.65
Code: 0xC0047062
Source: Data Flow Task 1 Source - test_Table [1]

Description: Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DtsCouldNotCreateManagedConnecti
onException: Could not create a managed connection manager.

at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.ManagedHelper.GetManagedConnection(String
assemblyQualifiedName, String connStr, Object transaction)
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper.IDTSConnectionManager100.AcquireCo
nnection(Object pTransaction)
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.DataReaderSourceAdapter.AcquireConnections(Object    
transaction)
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ManagedComponentHost.HostAcquireConnectio
ns(IDTSManagedComponentWrapper100 wrapper, Object transaction)
End Error
```

If I let the package run from the import wizard, by selecting the "run immediately" checkbox, it works fine. This let me think tat maybe there is something missing in the connection string that prevents from connecting to the databases properly.

For SQL Server (target DB) we use windows authentication to log into the database and username/password for Oracle (source DB).

I also tried to use the 32bit version of dtexec.exe, but without success.

Answer (score 1):

its strange that it doesn't say why it wasn't able to create the connection. I suspect drivers because if it was a login issue it would say that.

Did you explicitly run the 32 bit dtexec? This is very tricky and the reason I ask is because when packages are executed manually (double click) in a 64-bit environment with the 32-bit runtime installed, the 32-bit edition will be invoked by default (even though you are on 64 bits). This is because of the paths in the PATH environment variable: the directory to the 32-bit program files (%ProgramFiles(x86)%) is listed before the directory path to the 64-bit program files (%ProgramFiles%).

Remember that all the tools (BIDS and SSDT ) are 32-bit-only applications; although they can be used in a 64-bit environment, all the data providers they use are 32 bit. To enable the SSIS packages to be used in 64-bit environments, you must have the appropriate editions of the data providers; if you don’t; they will have to be executed using the 32-bit run time.

Comment: Hi Diego, yes in the command line I explicitly used the fullpath for the 32bit version of dtexec command (in the first lines generated by the dtexec.exe command I can read "32 bit version"). I thought the issue is related to the credentials, since executing the import directly from SQL Server wizard, it works fine. We can still run the import manually, but if possible I would have preferred a more "modern"/automated approach.